# Failed to bind properties under 'chaos.monkey.assaults' to de.codecentric.spring.boot.chaos.monkey.configuration.AssaultProperties

Tags: spring-boot-chaos-monkey

After adding choas Money Application start throwing "nAPPLICATION FAILED TO START" error.

**Springbot version** :

```
        <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
            </parent>
```

**Spring Cloud :**

```
        <dependencyManagement>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                        <scope>import</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                        <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                        <scope>import</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </dependencyManagement>
```

**Choas Monkey** :

```
        <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>chaos-monkey-spring-boot</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

**Error Logs :**

```
    "org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter",
    "message":"\r\n\r\n***************************\r\nAPPLICATION FAILED TO START\r\n***************************\r\n\r\n

    Description:\r\n\r\nBinding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: 
    Failed to bind properties under 'chaos.monkey.assaults' to de.codecentric.spring.boot.chaos.monkey.configuration.AssaultProperties
```

Comment: Can you please show your application.properties/yml. I think the error lies there

Comment: https://github.com/vaquarkhan/chaos-monkey-springboot/blob/master/chaos-monkey-demo/pom.xml

Comment: Thanks, I just started the application and it worked, so you figured it out what was wrong? ;)

Comment: Ya I will update my answer soon